# Display single lines of several files at command line

Tags: shell

My problem is the following: due to LaTeX wonderfulness, I often get errors with line numbers but no indication of which file is being referred to:

```
l.127 \end{table}
```

Is there a command that would allow me to only see output line 127, say, for multiple files (ideally with wildcarding).

This would probably be pretty easy to write in Python or similar, I just wondered if there was a simple way with common shell commands.

Note: a simple way to do this with a single file is (as pointed out below)

```
head -n 127 filename | tail -n 1
```

but this fails for multiple files.

OK, have just realised that a bash loop is an option:

```
for i in `ls $1`;
   do echo $i; head -n $2 $1 | tail -n 1;
done;
```

to be executed with syntax

```
source lineno.sh 127 filenames
```

Comment: It looks funny to be sourcing a shell script like that.  Make it executable and run it: `lineno.sh 127 filenames`.  I remove the `.sh` when I place such commands in my `$HOME/bin` directory so I can simply run: `lineno 127 filenames`.

Answer (score 1):

Also with awk:

```
awk 'FNR==127 {print FILENAME ":" $0; nextfile}' *.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks funny to be sourcing a shell script like that.  Make it executable and run it:

```
lineno.sh 127 filenames
```

I remove the `.sh` when I place such commands in my `$HOME/bin` directory so I can simply run:

```
lineno 127 filenames
```

The script is sub-optimal; you should avoid using `ls` like that (it wreaks merry hell on your file names if any of them contain spaces or other special characters).

```
#!/bin/sh
line=${1:?}  # Complains if there is no $1 or if it is an empty string
shift
for file in "$@"
do
    echo "$file";
    head -n $line "$file" | tail -n 1
done
```

I'd probably beef up the argument checking (to report the correct usage, insisting on at least a second argument), but it will work reasonably.